# segmentation fault in this little piece of code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

```
 char *commandstrings[MAXARGS];

    commandstr = strtok(line,"|");
    int i = 0;

    while(commandstr != NULL){
      commandstrings[i] = commandstr;
      printf("%s \n",commandstr);
      commandstr = strtok(NULL,"|");
      i++;
    }

     printf("first parsing complete!");
```

Hello guys. I'm trying to separate a string into various substrings using strtok and store them into an array of strings called "commandstrings".

the problem is that I get a segmentation fault just before reaching the final printf.
supposed i give as argument the line: "lol | omg | bbq"

the program prints:
lol
omg
bbq
segmentation fault (core dumped)

What could be the problem? I dont think i need to hassle you guys with the rest of the code since the "while" cycle executes nicely and the error occours just before leaving the cicle as the last print is not shown.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired but the error is not obvious to me at first glance (seems an off-by-one mistake though). +1 for posting the relevant part of the code after applying deductions based on logic. Rare bird on SO nowadays.

Comment: @Valiant Please post the complete program. Are you sure that it is crashing before your printf debug statement ?

Comment: As Sherlock Holmes would say, if you've eliminated all the code and your program still crashes, then your bug is in another castle. What is `line`?

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me. Also available at http://codepad.org/FZmK4usU

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char line[] = "lol | omg | bbq";
    enum{ MAXARGS = 10 };
    char const *commandstrings[MAXARGS];

    int i = 0;
    char * commandstr = strtok(line,"|");

    while(commandstr != NULL){
        commandstrings[i] = commandstr;
        printf("%s \n",commandstrings[ i ]);
        i++;
        commandstr = strtok(NULL,"|");
    }

    printf("first parsing complete!");
}
```

Comment: Well spotted, I've been breaking my head over trying it with a `char * line = ...`

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my code. The problem was in another function which I called after the final printf. I find it hard to understand why the final print didnt show if the segmentation problem was after it. Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: @ValiantValemore: The final `printf()` may not have shown because the output was not flushed before the segmentation problem occurred in the subsequent function.